# Placeholder not working in chrome

Tags: html, placeholder, asp.net-placeholder

I'm using razor view page and in date time field i want to display placeholder, its showing in Firefox but not showing in chrome its show - `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Hers is my code -

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control form-inline", @placeholder = "Date must be today's or past date" } })
```

[image: Screenshot of firefox]

[image: Screenshot of chrome]

How can i resolve this issue.??

Comment: Chrome only allows "international" date formats when rendering inputs with a `type="date"` value, by default. Your placeholder would need to be `YYYY/MM/DD`. Also, you only need to use the `@` operator to escape reserved words (like `class`) - it's not needed for placeholder. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format

Answer (score 0):

The date type doesn't support placeholder attribute. Also, the WebKit implementation says it's fixed.

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-input-element.html#input-type-attr-summary